# Any mobile app for Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion

I often find myself trying to Ask Ubuntu for advice or offer help but all i have with me is my smartphone. Is there any mobile app for Ask Ubuntu? Or is it going to be one? With Ubuntu coming to phones and tablets, i believe mobile users deserves fair treatment and help as good as PC people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes There is a offical app for the Stack Exchange sites.I have inserted the links bellow.

[Andriod](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin&hl=en),
[IOS](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a web app, using the mobile version of ask Ubuntu. I'm using it right now to write this answer.

Just search in Ubuntu store for 'Ask Ubuntu' and install it.